# Add JSON object to an specific key in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON with this structure:

```
[
   {
      "myKey":[
         {
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "value":2
         }
      ],
      "secondKey":[
         {
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "value":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

And I need to add objects evaluating the key, for example, for `myKey` add:

```
[
   {
      "myKey":[
         {
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "value":2
         },
         {
            "new value":3
         }
      ],
      "secondKey":[
         {
            "value":1
         },
         {
            "value":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What would be the correct way to do it, considering that I'm just using postgres select and procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb_set` with the original `myKey` array concatenated with `{"new value":3}`.
The CTE `t(j)` is for demonstration only.

```sql
with t(j) as ( values (
'[{
   "myKey":[{"value":1}, {"value":2}], "secondKey":[{"value":1},{"value":2}]
 }]'::jsonb))

SELECT jsonb_set(j, '{0, myKey}', j->0->'myKey' || '{"new value":3}')
FROM t;
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "myKey": [
      {
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "new value": 3
      }
    ],
    "secondKey": [
      {
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "value": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You may prefer to use `jsonb_build_object('new value', 3)` instead of `'{"new value":3}'`.